# How do I see questions from only communities I have already joined on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

I have poked around the site and have not yet found a way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set your own filters on https://stackexchange.com/filters

Here you can set your preferences regarding sites and/or certain tags where you want to see questions from. You can also opt-in to e-mail updates.

Comment: We could really use a link to that filters page on the page footer for every page.